# Hide rows based on the time total between two dates

Tags: excel, vba, hide, datediff

I would like 3 rows to show only if the difference between the effective date and the end date is greater than 6 months. I know how to hide rows and how datediff works but not sure how to bring it all together. I also need the code to run as soon as the date are entered Presently it only runs when I select "run" for the sub

This is the code I presently have and it works but it will go once I rune the macro....I need it to happen instantly once the dates are entered

Present macro but only works when "run"

```
Sub Priority()

If Range("K68") > DateSerial(Year(Range("H68")), Month(Range("H68")) + 6, Day(Range("H68"))+1) Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("72:74").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("72:74").EntireRow.Hidden = True

 End If

If Range("K68") > DateSerial(Year(Range("H68")), Month(Range("H68")) + 6, Day(Range("H68"))+1) Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("75:76").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("75:76").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question and include the code you already have tried. Tell us what is working already and where exactly you got stuck or errors. It is much more likely to get an answer if you show your effort. Otherwise people will think you want them to do all the work for you. Also please ask a question to your code.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't have provided any more information than the fact you want to bring `DateDiff()` and `Range.Hidden` together, I will give you an example for this.

```vb
If DateDiff("m", Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 2)) >= 6 Then
    Rows(2).Hidden = False
    Rows(3).Hidden = False
    Rows(4).Hidden = False
Else
    Rows(2).Hidden = True
    Rows(3).Hidden = True
    Rows(4).Hidden = True
End If
```

This would hide the rows `2` to `3` if `DateDiff()` returns a value greater or equal `6` for the dates in the first row and first two columns. If the value is smaller it will make them visible. Of course you can easily edit the column and row values to your needs.

`Cells(1, 1)` will return the value (in your case a date) of cell in the first row and first column, `Cells(1, 2)` for the first row and second column.

Please also note that `DateDiff()` will return `6` no matter of the day of the month if the first parameter is `"m"` and the difference of the months is `6`. If you want to be closer to exactly 6 months I would suggest to use `"d"` for days instead and set the condition to `>= 180` or something else more appealing to your needs.